# command line compliation error

Tags: perl, unix, terminal

Running into some problems with a one liner....

```
ls *.fq.gz | cut -f 1 -d . | uniq | perl -pe 'chomp; system "bwa-0.7.9a mem  -M /refs/GATK_bundle_2.3//human_g1k_v37.fasta -R'@RG\tID:Foo\tSM:bar' $_.1.fq.gz $_.2.fq.gz > $_.sam"'
```

Output is

```
[E::bwa_set_rg] the read group line is not started with @RG
CLMP10920-1[E::bwa_set_rg] the read group line is not started with @RG
CLMP10920-2[E::bwa_set_rg] the read group line is not started with @RG
CLMP10920-3[E::bwa_set_rg] the read group line is not started with @RG
CLMP10920-4W[E::bwa_set_rg] the read group line is not started with @RG
COL1A110908-1[E::bwa_set_rg] the read group line is not started with @RG
COL1A110908-2[E::bwa_set_rg] the read group line is not started with @RG
COL1A110908-3[E::bwa_set_rg] the read group line is not started with @RG
COL1A110908-4Wgleadalln@mgcl01:~/testing/analysis$
```

Done some reading around but struggling to find a solution for running this command - think it has something to do with the nested ' in the -R option part of the command.... is there any way to escape these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perl doesn't have a `sys` [function](http://p3rl.org/perlfunc). Did you mean [system](http://p3rl.org/system)?

Also, the syntax highlighter is correct about quotes. The signle quote in `R'@RG` ends the first single quoted string, which doesn't seem right.

Comment: @user3234810: Try to fix the quotes, then.

Comment: Is there a way to esape them? tried \ before each of the problem ' but this just results in a prompt (>)

Comment: @user3234810: In bash, you can use `\'`, but you need to do so outside of quotes. The usual usage is therefore `'quoted string part 1 '\'' part2'`.